# How to duplicate desktop in Linux with xrandr?

Tags: xrandr, display, deepin

Currently, I'm using Deepin OS 15.4.

By default Deepin sets the desktop to extended mode when a projector is connected, but what I want is to duplicate my screen.

I can't find it in the Control Center configuration, but I stumbled upon in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736948/extended-desktop-in-linux).

The above extends the monitor with xrandr,

How do I duplicate my desktop to the projector with xrandr?

Answer (score 27):

First find out the name of each display e.g. using `xrandr --current`. Then the following command should work to duplicate them.

```
 $ xrandr --output <projector> --same-as <desktop>
```

Comment: Yours was the only option that worked for me. Playing with panning was becoming a nightmare. The key was to leave alone the resolutions. Thxs!

Comment: That doesn't work well if monitors have different resolution.

Answer (score 21):

I use this command to mirror my desktop with my external VGA:

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.711x0.711
```

`LVDS-1` is the laptop screen , natively working in 1366x768.

`VGA-1` is my external VGA monitor, with native resolution of 1920x1080, scaled to 0.711 which equals close to 1366x768 (laptop resolution).

Results are good for me. You can experiment with those options.

Similarly, I use this one for extended desktop:

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --left-of VGA-1
```

You can detect the names of your screens by just running `xrandr`

Answer (score 2):

A little shell script I wrote to mirror all monitors connected. You shouldn't have to worry about figuring out which monitors are available. This should handle that.

```
RESOLUTION=1920x1080
xrandr --listmonitors | sed -n '1!p' | sed -e 's/\s[0-9].*\s\([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\)$/\1/g' | xargs -n 1 -- bash -xc 'xrandr --output $0 --mode '$RESOLUTION' --pos 0x0 --rotate normal'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`arandr`](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) to graphically set up your screen layout, you can just drag the one screen over the other (so they are stacked on top of each other), and then set the resolutions to be the same (or different, i.e. one will be cropped)